# VirtualBox. net use invalid command

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Debian Squeeze as a guest. I try to setup share folder. From manual: type net use x: \vboxsvr\MySharedFiles in command prompt. But I get error: net use: invalid command. I installed net, but it doesn't know "use" command.

Comment: Why do you run commands from the Windows section of the manual on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net use x: \vboxsvr\MySharedFiles` is the command to use for Windows guests that want to access the share, for linux guests you should follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders).

Comment: In fact both Windows and Linux commands are present in the official VBox manual, no need to use anything else.

Comment: Yup you are actually right but that one was the first I found that lists the exact command with explanations.